# Demonstrating that double Affine encryption offers no additional security compared to single encryption

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography

I'm currently taking an online Cryptography course, and one of the assignments is to demonstrate that encrypting data multiple times with the Affine cipher does not actually enhance its security. I've been working on this and I believe the final encrypted values should be the same (they unfortunately aren't). I'm new to Cryptography, can't wait to see your advises

```
int main() {

    char charArray[1] = "K";
    char charArrayClone[1] = "K";


    int a1 = 3;
    int b1 = 5;

    int a2 = 7;
    int b2 = 11;

    int firstTest;

    charArrayClone[0] = affineEncryption(charArray[0], a1, b1);

    printf("First Affine Enc. Result: %d\n", charArrayClone[0]);

    charArrayClone[0] = affineEncryption(charArrayClone[0], a2, b2);

    printf("Second Affine Enc. Result: %d\n", charArrayClone[0]);

    printf("Saving and resetting for second stage... %d -> %d\n", charArrayClone[0], charArray[0]);

    firstTest = charArrayClone[0];
    charArrayClone[0] = charArray[0];

    printf("Clone Value: %d\n", charArrayClone[0]);
    printf("Result successful! Processing Ek3 Enc. ...\n");

    int a3 = a1 + a2;
    int b3 = b1 + b2;

    charArrayClone[0] = affineEncryption(charArrayClone[0], a3, b3);

    printf("Ek3 Encryption Result: %d\n", charArrayClone[0]);

    printf("Ready to compare results!");

    if(charArrayClone[0] == firstTest) {
        printf("Result proven! Good job!");
    } else printf("A3/B3 values are wrong, exiting...");

    return 0;
}



char affineEncryption(char theChar, int a, int b) {

    int y;

    int x = char2int(theChar);

    y = (a * x + b) % 26;

    return int2char(y);
}
```

Output:

```
First Affine Enc. Result: 74
Second Affine Enc. Result: 87
Saving and resetting for second stage... 87 -> 75
Clone Value: 75
Result successful! Processing Ek3 Enc. ...
Ek3 Encryption Result: 77
Ready to compare results!
A3/B3 values are wrong, exiting...
```

Comment: Not any sort of rigorous answer, but I would think it's something along the lines of "Double affine encryption is simply single affine encryption using a different key".

Comment: _Side note:_ `char charArray[1] = "K";` is invalid because `charArray` only has room for one `char`, while `"K"` requires two. Gotta leave room for the null character (`'\0'`) that terminates the string literal. Ditto for `char charArrayClone[1] = "K";`. The easy fix is to omit the size: `char charArray[] = "K";`.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe the final encrypted values should be the same (they unfortunately aren't).

The reason they are different is because the calculation of `a3` and `b3` for the combined encryptions is wrong.

You cannot simply add the the values together.

```cpp
int a3 = a1 + a2;  // adding is wrong
int b3 = b1 + b2;
```

If you let `p` be the plaintext integer, and let `e1` and `e2` represent the encrypted integers, you have this transformation:

```cpp
int e1 = a1 * p + b1;   // (1)
int e2 = a2 * e1 + b2;  // (2)
```

Substituting equation (1) into equation (2) gives:

```cpp
int e2 = a2 * (a1 * p + b1) + b2;
```

Rearranging:

```cpp
int e2 = (a1 * a2) * p + (a2 * b1 + b2);
```

By inspection:

```cpp
int a3 = a1 * a2;
int b3 = a2 * b1 + b2;
```

Using these values for `a3` and `b3` gives you the result you desire.

##### Including the modulus does not change the result

Although the foregoing calculations ignore the mod operations, that turns out to be okay. Without going into all the details, there are certain properties that can be proven for [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Basic_properties).

For example, `[(a mod m) * (b mod m)] mod m` equals `(a * b) mod m`.

A similar result holds for addition.

##### Side note

When you initialize a character array with a string literal, you have to leave room for the null character (`'\0'`) that terminates the string literal. The easiest way to accomplish this is to omit the array size, and let the compiler figure it out for you.

```cpp
char charArray[] = "K";         // omit the array size
char charArrayClone[] = "K";    // compiler chooses size == 2
```